# Puppeteerjs cant run headless with proxies

Tags: javascript, proxy, puppeteer

I have this code right here that opens a browser and pushes it inside an array, anyway iam trying to use a proxy ip to launch the browser with but everytime the pages i try to go to never load and they just give me an error like This site cant be reached OR ERR NETWORK RESET / ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED etc, here is the code iam using, and also i use this website to get the proxies http://free-proxy.cz/en/

```
      bots.browsers.push(await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, 
        args:[
        '--start-maximized',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--proxy-server=52.149.152.236:80'
        ]
        
      
      }));
      
    }
```

Comment: I believe you need the http:// part in the proxy-server arg

Comment: i already tried that but doesnt work either

Comment: That means the proxy is no good then.

Comment: Oh, mate, free proxies **cannot** be trusted or relied upon.

Comment: can you guys guide me to a website that sells proxies? (a good website with good proxies)